# How to change vector to bullet point list for htmlOutput?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I change vector to bullet point list for htmlOutput? After clicking on data table row, I would like to have a detailed characteristics of each character where vehicle, starship and movie should be listed starting from bullet point. Here is my code, apologize that it is a little bit messy, I have started my R journey not so long ago.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)


# 1) Prepare layout


hair = starwars %>%
  select(hair_color) %>%
  arrange(hair_color) %>% 
  distinct()


spec = starwars %>% 
  select(species) %>% 
  arrange(species) %>% 
  distinct()


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('hair', 'Hair', hair, multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('spec', 'Species', spec, multiple = TRUE),
      htmlOutput('txt')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput('plot'),
      dataTableOutput('table')
    )
  )
)

# 2) Prepare data

srv <- function(input, output){

  starwars_data <- reactive({
    starwars_data_as_table <- as.data.frame(starwars)
    starwars_data_as_table = starwars_data_as_table %>%
      tibble::rownames_to_column(var = 'ID')

    starwars_data_as_table$gender[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$gender)] <- 'not applicable'
    starwars_data_as_table$homeworld[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$homeworld)] <- 'unknown'
    starwars_data_as_table$species[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$species)] <- 'unknown'
    starwars_data_as_table$hair_color[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$hair_color)] <- 'not applicable'

    # a) add missing info

    starwars_data = starwars_data_as_table %>%
      mutate(
        height = case_when(
          name == 'Finn' ~ as.integer(178),
          name == 'Rey' ~ as.integer(170),
          name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ as.integer(172),
          name == 'BB8' ~ as.integer(67),
          name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ as.integer(200),
          TRUE ~ height
        ),
        mass = case_when(
          name == 'Finn' ~ 73,
          name == 'Rey' ~ 54,
          name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ 80,
          name == 'BB8' ~ 18,
          name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ 76,
          TRUE ~ mass
        ),
        film_counter = lengths(films),
        vehicle_counter = lengths(vehicles),
        starship_counter = lengths(starships)
      )

    colnames(starwars_data) <- c("ID", "Name","Height", "Weight",
                                 "Hair","Skin","Eyes",
                                 "Birth", "Gender", 
                                 "Homeworld","Species", "Movies",
                                 "Vehicles", "Starship", "Number of movies", 
                                 "Number of vehicles", "Number of starships")
    starwars_data

  })


  starwars_data_filtered <-  reactive({

    dta <- starwars_data()
    if(length(input$hair) > 0){
      dta <- dta %>% 
        filter(Hair %in% input$hair)
    }
    if (length(input$spec) > 0) {
      dta <-  dta %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$spec)
    } 
    if (length(input$spec) > 0 & length(input$hair) > 0) {
      dta <-  dta %>% 
        filter(Hair %in% input$hair) %>% 
        filter(Species %in% input$spec)
    }
    dta
  })



  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(starwars_data_filtered(),
            source = 'scatter') %>%
      add_markers(
        x = ~Height,
        y = ~Homeworld,
        color = ~factor(Gender),
        key = ~ID
      ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(title = 'Height', rangemode = "tozero"),
        yaxis = list(title = 'Homeland', rangemode = "tozero"),
        dragmode = "select"
      )
  })


  selected_data = reactive({
    sel_data = starwars_data_filtered() %>%
      select(ID,
             Name,
             Height,
             Weight,
             Hair,
             'Birth',
             'Number of movies',
             'Number of vehicles',
             'Number of starships')
    ed = event_data("plotly_selected", source = "scatter")
    if(!is.null(ed)){
      sel_data = sel_data %>%
        filter(ID %in% ed$key)       
    }
    sel_data 
  })

  output$table = renderDataTable({
    d = selected_data()
    if(!is.null(d)){
      datatable(d, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE)
    }
  })

  output$txt = renderText({
    row_count <-  input$table_rows_selected
    if(!is.null(row_count)){
      paste("Name: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Name"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Gender: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Gender"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Birth: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Birth"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Homeworld: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Homeworld"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Species: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Species"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Height: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Height"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Weight: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Weight"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Hair: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Hair"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Skin: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Skin"],"<br>","</b>",
            "Eyes: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Eyes"],"<br>","</b>",
            "<br>",
            "Vehicles: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Vehicles"],"<br>","</b>",
            "<br>",
            "Starship: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Starship"],"<br>","</b>",
            "<br>",
            "Movies: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Movies"],"<br>","</b>")
    }
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function to turn a vector into a [bulleted list in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp):

```
## write a function to turn a vector into bulleted list
vectorBulletList <- function(vector) {
    if(length(vector > 1)) {
        paste0("<ul><li>", 
               paste0(
                   paste0(vector, collpase = ""), collapse = "</li><li>"),
               "</li></ul>")   
    }
}
# example
testVector <- c("apple", "orange", "banana", "pineapple")
vectorBulletList(testVector)
```

However, your code (`starwars_data()[row_count, "Movies"]`) returns a list instead of a character vector. If we look at the class of the `films`, `vehicles`, and `starships` columns in the `starwars` dataframe, we see that they are all lists. Selecting one observation from the `films` column returns a list of length 1. So we'll need to select the first element of the list to return a character vector.

```
## class of starwars columns: films, vehicles, starships
starwars_data <- as.data.frame(starwars)
sapply(starwars_data[, c("films", "vehicles", "starships")], class)

## class and length of one observation from films column
class(starwars_data[1, "films"])
length(starwars_data[1, "films"])

## select first element of list to return character vector
class(starwars_data[1, "films"][[1]])
starwars_data[1, "films"][[1]]
```

We can put this all together in your script as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)


# 1) Prepare layout


hair = starwars %>%
    select(hair_color) %>%
    arrange(hair_color) %>% 
    distinct()


spec = starwars %>% 
    select(species) %>% 
    arrange(species) %>% 
    distinct()


ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput('hair', 'Hair', hair, multiple = TRUE),
            selectInput('spec', 'Species', spec, multiple = TRUE),
            htmlOutput('txt')
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput('plot'),
            dataTableOutput('table')
        )
    )
)

# 2) Prepare data

srv <- function(input, output){

    starwars_data <- reactive({
        starwars_data_as_table <- as.data.frame(starwars)
        starwars_data_as_table = starwars_data_as_table %>%
            tibble::rownames_to_column(var = 'ID')

        starwars_data_as_table$gender[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$gender)] <- 'not applicable'
        starwars_data_as_table$homeworld[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$homeworld)] <- 'unknown'
        starwars_data_as_table$species[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$species)] <- 'unknown'
        starwars_data_as_table$hair_color[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$hair_color)] <- 'not applicable'

        # a) add missing info

        starwars_data = starwars_data_as_table %>%
            mutate(
                height = case_when(
                    name == 'Finn' ~ as.integer(178),
                    name == 'Rey' ~ as.integer(170),
                    name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ as.integer(172),
                    name == 'BB8' ~ as.integer(67),
                    name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ as.integer(200),
                    TRUE ~ height
                ),
                mass = case_when(
                    name == 'Finn' ~ 73,
                    name == 'Rey' ~ 54,
                    name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ 80,
                    name == 'BB8' ~ 18,
                    name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ 76,
                    TRUE ~ mass
                ),
                film_counter = lengths(films),
                vehicle_counter = lengths(vehicles),
                starship_counter = lengths(starships)
            )

        colnames(starwars_data) <- c("ID", "Name","Height", "Weight",
                                     "Hair","Skin","Eyes",
                                     "Birth", "Gender", 
                                     "Homeworld","Species", "Movies",
                                     "Vehicles", "Starship", "Number of movies", 
                                     "Number of vehicles", "Number of starships")
        starwars_data

    })


    starwars_data_filtered <-  reactive({

        dta <- starwars_data()
        if(length(input$hair) > 0){
            dta <- dta %>% 
                filter(Hair %in% input$hair)
        }
        if (length(input$spec) > 0) {
            dta <-  dta %>% 
                filter(Species %in% input$spec)
        } 
        if (length(input$spec) > 0 & length(input$hair) > 0) {
            dta <-  dta %>% 
                filter(Hair %in% input$hair) %>% 
                filter(Species %in% input$spec)
        }
        dta
    })



    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(starwars_data_filtered(),
                source = 'scatter') %>%
            add_markers(
                x = ~Height,
                y = ~Homeworld,
                color = ~factor(Gender),
                key = ~ID
            ) %>%
            layout(
                xaxis = list(title = 'Height', rangemode = "tozero"),
                yaxis = list(title = 'Homeland', rangemode = "tozero"),
                dragmode = "select"
            )
    })


    selected_data = reactive({
        sel_data = starwars_data_filtered() %>%
            select(ID,
                   Name,
                   Height,
                   Weight,
                   Hair,
                   'Birth',
                   'Number of movies',
                   'Number of vehicles',
                   'Number of starships')
        ed = event_data("plotly_selected", source = "scatter")
        if(!is.null(ed)){
            sel_data = sel_data %>%
                filter(ID %in% ed$key)       
        }
        sel_data 
    })

    output$table = renderDataTable({
        d = selected_data()
        if(!is.null(d)){
            datatable(d, selection = 'single', rownames = FALSE)
        }
    })

    output$txt = renderText({
        row_count <-  input$table_rows_selected
        if(!is.null(row_count)){

            # write a function to create a list from the vector
            vectorBulletList <- function(vector) {
                if(length(vector > 1)) {
                    paste0("<ul><li>", 
                           paste0(
                               paste0(vector, collpase = ""), collapse = "</li><li>"),
                           "</li></ul>")   
                }
            }

            # in starwars dataframe, vehicles and starships are lists
            # need to select the first element of the list (the character vector)
            vehicles <- starwars_data()[row_count, "Vehicles"][[1]]
            starships <- starwars_data()[row_count, "Starship"][[1]]
            movies <- starwars_data()[row_count, "Movies"][[1]]

            paste("Name: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Name"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Gender: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Gender"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Birth: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Birth"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Homeworld: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Homeworld"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Species: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Species"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Height: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Height"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Weight: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Weight"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Hair: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Hair"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Skin: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Skin"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "Eyes: ", "<b>",starwars_data()[row_count,"Eyes"],"<br>","</b>",
                  "<br>",
                  "Vehicles: ", "<b>", vectorBulletList(vehicles),"<br>","</b>",
                  "<br>",
                  "Starship: ", "<b>", vectorBulletList(starships),"<br>","</b>",
                  "<br>",
                  "Movies: ", "<b>", vectorBulletList(movies),"<br>","</b>")
        }
    })


}
shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

Comment: This more than I could expect! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I've just found bug in my code. Table is not refreshing correctly. It points to the right observation when I run it for the first time, but then when I am selecting characters using plot and try to get some info by clicking on the row, it still shows me the previous one (eg for the 1st row -> Luke Skywalker).  Not sure yet what is going on..

Comment: Will you open a new question with your issue and updated code? It'll make it easier to answer

Comment: Thanks. I have opened a new question.